# Laravel reducing relationship queries

Tags: laravel, relation

I have two models. `Expense` and `Method`. I want to grab the `sum` of all `expenses` for each `method type`. I have four types:

```
- bank
- credit-card
- wallet
- savings
```

Each Expense belongsTo a Method and each Method hasMany Expenses. So it's a One-to-Many relation. So a `method_id` is stored for each Expense.

The following query works to get the sum of all expenses that have a method with the type `bank` for example:

```php
$type = 'bank';

$expenses = auth()->user()->expenses()->with('method')->whereHas('method', function ($query) use ($type) {
        $query->where('type', $type);
    })->sum('amount');
```

But the thing is, if I want to get the total amount of all expenses for each method type, I will have to run too many queries. I would prefer just grabbing all Expenses, and then filtering through them to get the sum of all expenses for each method type.

The following for example doesn't work:

```php
$expenses = auth()->user()->expenses()->with('method')->get();

    $bank_balance = $expenses->filter(function ($expense)
    {
        $expense->whereHas('method', function ($query) {
            $query->where('type', 'bank');
        })->get(); // with or without ->get()
    });
```

Any ideas how to get what I want by not using too many queries?

Edit:

I've unaccepted the chosen answer because it didn't give me what I needed in the end. I need to be able to do something like this in my view:

```php
{{ $bank_balance }}
```

Which means, with xyz's answer, I wouldn't be able to do that, since I cannot distinguish between them. I only get results based on method_id's, but I need to be able to distinguish them by the method name.

DigitalDrifter's answer is the one that almost does the trick, but it gives me this:

```php
Collection {#800 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    "bank" => Collection {#797 ▼
      #items: array:30 [▼
        0 => array:2 [▼
          "type" => "bank"
          "amount" => 1536
        ]
        1 => array:2 [▶]
        2 => array:2 [▶]
        3 => array:2 [▶]
        4 => array:2 [▶]
        5 => array:2 [▶]
      ]
    }
    "credit-card" => Collection {#798 ▶}
    "wallet" => Collection {#799 ▶}
  ]
}
```

And I basically need something simple like this:

"bank" => "total sum here for all expenses that have a method of 'bank'"
"credit-card" => "total sum here for all expenses that have a method of 'credit-card'"

And so on..

I think this bit `->groupBy('type')->each->sum('amount')` does the trick, but not completely. It does group by type but it does not give a sum for each type, as you can see in the collection example above.

Comment: With xyz's answer you can access `$expenses->firstWhere('method.type', 'bank')->amount`, can't you? just make sure to include method_id in the select statement. Note that the `firstWhere` method is just for filtering the loaded collection, so it doesn't run a query.

Comment: From a performance point a view, xyz's answer is way faster than DigitalDrifter's one, grouping/summing/filtering large data with PHP is too slow compared to a Database engine. If you you want to even improve xyz's answer, I would replace `with('method')` with `selectRaw('SUM(amount) as total, methods.type')->join('methods', 'methods.id', '=' , 'expenses.method_id')->groupBy('method_id', 'methods.type')`, that way you hit the database only once and the results are already well formated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group by the method id and then sum the result in a select statement.

The following is untested.

```
$expenses = auth()->user()
                  ->expenses()
                  ->select(DB::raw('SUM(amount) as total'), 'other_select_fields', ...)
                  ->with('method')
                  ->groupBy('method_id')
                  ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using the available collection methods:

```
$expenses = auth()->user()->expenses()->with('method')->get();

$groupedSums = $expenses->map(function ($expense) {
    return [
        'type' => $expense['method']['type'],
        'amount' => $expense['method']['amount']
    ];
})->groupBy('type')->each->sum('amount');
```

Comment: Removed my comment here and edited my answer, perhaps you can check my edit and help fixing the last bit :)